# MySQL running a query faster as a Subquery than plain

Tags: mysql, subquery

Can anyone tell me why this subquery method is faster than a plain query? As far as I can tell they're identical in theory :S

```
SELECT
    temp.`[thing]`,
FROM ( SELECT 
    `[thing]`
FROM 
    `[table]`  
WHERE 
    [things] ) temp
```

is faster than:

```
SELECT 
    `[thing]`
FROM 
    `[table]`  
WHERE 
    `[things]`
```

The one in the subquery is over 5x faster...

Can anyone tell me what in my config could cause such an issue?

Cheers.

Considering quite a number of people didn't get the question I'll rephrase. The queries do the same thing. They are the same but in one the result is referenced from a outerquery the other is just plain.

```
SELECT `name` FROM `members` WHERE `member_id` = 1
```

or

```
SELECT tmp.`name` FROM ( SELECT `name` FROM `members` WHERE `member_id` = 1 ) tmp
```

Lets say member_id is the primary key and is the only index of members.

Any other info you want to know about this odd issue just ask in a comment and I'll provide. Without just giving you a dump of my whole setup I don't know what is causing this issue hence the lack of general information and the question is "what in my setup could cause this".

Do it yourself, run a generic SELECT statement then run it again with itself in a subquery and see if it is faster on your system.

Edit: accepted answer isn't really the answer but it is the only answer I've been given so I'll close the question.

Comment: Make sure you use SQL_NO_CACHE, and run each query several times *(to ensure all data is in RAM, and no disk-access is made, like the frist time that data is accessed)* ; do you still get the same result ?

Comment: i dont think anyone can answer this without the body of the queries and some info about your DBMS, indices, etc

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN has it dead-on.... if you have the query already in the cache, it doesn't have to hit the drive again, especially during repeated query attempts.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to "Why is '[car-a]' more fuel-efficient than '[car-b]'?".  Without knowing a lot more about the _actual_ statements and the db schema, any answer is just a guess.  It _might_ be caching, it might not.

Comment: Acutally it is the same query so I didn't think you'd need more info. I'll edit the statement to be a "real" example but my point is what Pascal MARTIN Was trying to say. @ Pascal MARTIN. The thing is, I can run the one in the subquery 5 times with the same result and the plain one 5 times with the larger time so it isn't caching!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only plausible explanation is caching. Not just MySQL caching, but also OS level caching like disk cache. Even if you use the SQL_NO_CACHE cache directive, that just means MySQL won't cache that query result. MySQL will still cache the index and table through normal caching methods.

You would really need to make sure you cache in clear, then reverse your queries, running the sub-select first. Then see if you get the same result. Also, you should run them both multiple times. It's very likely that you'll see that only first query is "slow".

Comment: I've done it. If I run the subquery one 10 times, it ends up at around the same speed each time which is still 5x faster than the other one ran 10 times. Bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo or are you pre-filtering the table in the subselect?

`[things]` vs. `[thing]` in the `WHERE` statements